# How to customize file name of Jenkins archive artifact plugin post build action?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins archive artifact plugin compress files into "archive.zip" file. It has always the same file name. Even more, Jenkins doesn't archive actually(there is no any "archive.zip" files in "builds" directories). Jenkins just map url

https://www.my-jenkins-server.com/jenkins/job/$job_name/$job_number/artifact/*zip*/archive.zip

and always return everything in job directory, those matches to pattern configured in post build action archive artifact plugin.

Problem is, that job itself generates ZIP archive, so I need to publish this archive under original name. It is important, since archive's name clarify owner of job, data inside, parameters used to run job. Let's say users ran job 10 times using different parameters and don't wait each job to finish before to run next. Later user will start download results and get

```
archive.zip
archive(1).zip
archive(2).zip
...
archive(10).zip
```

Now he needs to extract archives from those downloaded archives, to get 10 another archives with qualified names. Then delete those downloaded archive.  After that, identify by qualified archive name those he needs actually and delete rest of then. Easy to make mistake here, delete or miss archive file.

Solutions for me are:

1. Publish generated by job archive under it's original name.
2. Generate my files and form file name of archive under with it should be served, skip zipping inside of job. Final step, pass this file name as parameter into archive artifact plugin post build action, so Jenkins will serve archive under special name configured by job itself.

Comment: 1. do you have multiple file that you need to archive? 2. why not adding a step that create a zip / tar from them and name according to a parameter's value?

Comment: Well, this is an open issue at jenkins : https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8041 go and vote for it :) (or propose a patch O:) )

Answer (score 3):

The name of the zip file is determined from the directory that contains the artifacts (see Jenkins [source](https://github.com/kohsuke/jenkins/blob/55203ebeed1b7e182878d3e3c1184ac042f20473/core/src/main/resources/hudson/model/DirectoryBrowserSupport/dir.jelly#L93)).

- Internally, the top-most artifact directory has the name `archive`, that's why you will always see `archive.zip`.
- Conversely, this means that you can get a custom zip file `xyz.zip` by putting the artifacts in a (sub-)directory `xyz`.

There are no other options to change the name.

Answer (score 2):

You can run any post-build script (shell/batch/powershell) after the archive step, and rename archive.zip to archive_${BUILD_NUMBER}.zip so that you can easily track of the archive by the last successful build number of the job. But to do this, first you need to clean the workspace to keep a track of the archive files based on the build number.